# Using regex as search string for python's "in" keyword

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a dictionary of sets of paths:

```
my_dict['some_key'] = {'abc/hi/you','xyz/hi/you','jkl/hi/you'}
```

I want to see if a path appears is in this set. If I have the whole path I simply would do the following:

```
str = 'abc/hi/you'
if str in my_dict['some_key']:
    print(str)
```

But what if I don't know `b` is what comes in between `a` and `c`. What if it could be literally anything. If I was `ls`ing in a shell I'd just put `*` and call it a day.

What I want to be able to do is have str be a regx:

```
regx = '^a.*c/hi/you$' #just assume this is the ideal regex. Doesn't really matter.
if regx in my_dict['some_key']:
    print('abc/hi/you') #print the actual path, not the regx
```

What is a clean and fast way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the set rather than a simple in call.

To avoid setting up the whole dictionary of sets for the example I have abstracted it as simply my_set.

```
import re
my_set = {'abc/hi/you','xyz/hi/you','jkl/hi/you'}
regx  = re.compile('^a.*c/hi/you$')
for path in my_set:
    if regx.match(path):
        print(path)
```

I chose to compile instead of simply `re.match()` because the set could have 1 million plus elements in the actual implementation.

Comment: While needing to print the actual path and not the regex breaks the typical "formula" of ```if x in y: print(x)``` it is important to note this doesn't change the fact that I don't think it is possible to even do ```if regx in y: print(regx)```

Comment: no need to compile, `re` uses a recently used cache of regex strings

Comment: Why do you answer your own question within 1 minute? And give a comment on the answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: regarding the compiling, I was under the impression that compiling once was slightly faster for very large number of cache checks? Maybe I was mistaken. Also, due to the nature of the broader program (outside of what is shown in the question) it makes a bit more sense to compile from a readability perspective imo.

Comment: Maybe in the Python2 days but for Python3 the speed increase is very small, checking the regex to the string takes considerable more time than the cache check

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the `set` class and implement the `a in b` operator

```python
import re
from collections import defaultdict

class MySet(set):
  def __contains__(self, regexStr):
    regex = re.compile(regexStr)
    for e in self:
      if regex.match(e):
        return True
    return False

my_dict = defaultdict(MySet)

my_dict['some_key'].add('abc/hi/you')

regx = '^a.*c/hi/you$'
if regx in my_dict['some_key']:
    print('abc/hi/you')
```